# Referencing "instanceof"/prototype from another scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS, you often build an object from a factory that normally occupies a different function scope then the controller (although this could be my design and practice problem). Suppose you need to do some logic (either in the controller, service, whatever you have, the point is the logic needs to be done in a different scope the object was created in so the constructor is not defined)

For example, you normally might have:

```
Global scope
     Factory scope
         - Object returns
     Controller scope
          - Injection of factory returns the object
```

Or in better terms:

```
var x = (function() {
    function Thing() {}
    return new Thing();
})();
//How can I check x is instance of Thing if Thing is not defined in this scope?
```

I have tried `x instanceof Thing` or `x.constructor == Thing`, but obviously the inherent problem is that the `Thing()` constructor is not defined in the scope. How can I overcome this (or what practice is there) as I would imagine this problem is quite inconvenient and rather common)?

Comment: why not defining ```Thing``` at a scope visible by the factory and controller ?

Comment: If you instantiate only one `Thing` (here: `x`), you should not make it a class. If you want to instantiate multiple ones, you should not recreate the class every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use Angular DI for everything you may need across the app.

```
  app
    .value('Thing', Thing)
    .factory('thing', function (Thing) {
      return new Thing;
    })
    .controller('Some', function (thing, Thing) {
      thing instanceof Thing === true;
    });

  function Thing() { ... }
```

Comment: But how can I instantiate the constructor from this?

Comment: With `new Thing`. See `thing` service.